# Strategy of restoring database with multiple logging files (24 total) at once

Tags: restore, transaction-log

I am trying to see whether it is safe and efficient approach if I run a multiple line of SQL command to restore multiple (total 24) logging files at once.

These files are formatted in **bak** file format, but they are all hourly transactional log files.

I have these SQL statements to run all together:

```
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051800.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051801.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051802.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051803.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051804.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051805.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051806.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051807.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051808.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051809.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051810.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051811.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051812.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051813.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051814.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051815.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051816.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051817.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051818.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051819.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051820.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051821.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051822.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica] FROM DISK = 'F:\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021051823.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
```

Bottom is screenshot of each files and its size:

[image]

Because size of each file could be pretty big at one point (for example: ".._**2021051804.bak**" file is much bigger size than others, I am not sure whether running the whole SQL statement at once is a good approach.

Or should I break down these whole process into separate SQL Server Agent job steps?

I am not sure how SQL behaves when these whole SQL statement gets executed at once.

Does it run one by one from the top (stops until one is done then goes to the next line) and would not skip any process along the line (if one process takes longer than the other)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

SQL Server runs each statement within the batch to completion before starting the next one.

The last restore in the sequence should specify `STANDBY` if you want the resulting database to be readable, with the option to apply further logs in future.

`.bak` is not a file format, it is an ordinary Windows file extension. SQL Server does not care about that. Different people use different conventions. A popular one is `.bak` for a full backup and `.trn` for transaction logs, but it is just a convention.